# Where can I get a list of all possible angular2 imports in ngModule?

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

So we have a code like this to bootstrap an app.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

We import **BrowserModule**. But what is BrowserModule? Api reference doesn't give much explanation. What for do we use it. And what modules can we use more, except BrowserModule ?
I want to understand angular2 on a deeper level. That's why asking those questions.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=module

Answer (score 1):

`BrowserModule` provides services that are essential to launch and run a browser app, if it wont be imported your application would throw an error and would not run on **any browser**. For further clarifications and common questions you may have answers [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-what-to-import) and [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html).